# How do I get the SOAP response when there was an exception?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, response

I made a call to a third party web service and get back an ESOAPHTTPException with a message in this format:

Cryptic message here - URL: http://webserviceurl - SOAPAction: performWithArgList

Now the support personnel for this web service has asked for the full SOAP response. Normally, I would attach an event handler to THTTPRIO.OnAfterExecute and simply store the content of the stream I receive as parameter.

But since Delphi raises the exception, that event handler doesn't execute. I understand that the exception may in fact mean that the service had failed in some catastrophic way, but there should still be some kind of response (not a timeout error).

Is there some other method I can use to trap the response *before* Delphi turns it into an exception?

Comment: Use SOAPUI to talk to the web service step by step. That should get you the response you need. http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Sorry, Delphi 2010. I'm not aware of changes in XE that could be relevant, but I could of course be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an ERemotableException-based exception you'd want to look at the OnAfterExecute event as it represents a fault sent back by the Service... but for ESOAPHTTPException (your case) you'll want to handle the OnWinInetError event ( http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SOAPHTTPTrans.THTTPReqResp.OnWinInetError).

D2010 introduced a bug in the SOAP HTTP handling. The typical symptom is that it would miss HTTP failures (such as when the Server is busy). So maybe that's not the issue you're running into but without knowing the exact error code or message you're seeing, one cannot tell. You can find more details here:  https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=304898&tstart=0

For example, if you're getting the error about 'Handle is in the wrong state', the issue mentioned above is the culprit. It means that the 'Send' failed but the runtime happily proceeded to read a response. You can find out more about that one from this thread: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=307048.

So you should handle OnWinInetError and grab the error code (LastError param). That's probably key to understanding the failure.

Cheers,

Bruneau

Comment: Wow! Great answer. My error message is in fact "Handle in the wrong state" and my own investigations suggested it may have to do with the volume of data sent. That didn't make sense to me, but it does if I take into your description of the bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the RIO event to examine the response before it is deserialized.

OnAfterExecute

You'll get the response as a stream, which you can convert to a string. Then you can examine for bad things like exceptions, beign totally empty, or starting with '', which usually (in my case) indicates that the service isn't up.

Comment: This is what I tried first, but it didn't work at all. The exception was raised before this event handler. Since the message I received back contained "performWithArgList" I think the problem actually occurs when doing the call, without the actual web service getting an opportunity to respond. But that failure should still be reported and it doesn't seem to happen at a point I can intercept. I think I'll use WireShark what's going through the pipe.

Comment: In this case, you're likely not receiving an response.  In that case, use the RIO_BeforeExecute to log the outbound request, and submit that to the server via SoapUI to see what's going on.

Comment: In addition (or instead of WireShark), you can try Fiddler2. It's very useful for sniffing SOAP requests, and inserts itself as a proxy for anything using the WinInet stack.  Note that SoapUI won't show up in that, as it's using a Java stack.

Answer (score 1):

I would open the source for SOAPHTTPTrans and put a break point inside THTTPReqResp.Check(), just inside the "if error".  When you hit the breakpoint, you'll have more of an idea what's wrong. Look at the call stack to see how you got here.  It's probably something going wrong with your reqest being created and sent. If it's during the send, then it's likely not ever going out on the network so you won't see it with WireShark, Fiddler, or SoapUI.

IMO, functions like Check() should have an extra parameter for CallerLocation, so that instead of calling this:
Check(not Assigned(Request), False);
you'd call this:
Check(not Assigned(Request), False, 'THTTPReqResp.SendGet');
and Check would append CallerLocation to the error message, and you'd know (a lot) more about what's going on.